# python: how to merge multiple lists into one?

Tags: python, web-scraping

how could I get to make these three lists into one list following the same order as the output in the join?
Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.adorocinema.com/filmes/mais-esperados/'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

html_filme = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'gd-col-left'})
html_filme2 = html_filme.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'meta-title-link'})
#print(html_series.prettify())
#print(html_series2)

filmeLista = []

for texto in html_filme2:
    filme = texto.find_all(text=True)
    filmeLista.append({'nome': filme[0]})
    #print (serieLista)

diretoresLista = []

html_diretores = html_filme.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'meta-body-item meta-body-direction'})
for diretor in html_diretores:
    diretores = diretor.find_all(text = True)
    diretoresLista.append({'diretor':diretores[3]})
    #print(diretores)
    #print(diretoresLista)

estreiasLista = []

html_estreia = html_filme.find_all('div' ,attrs={'class' : 'meta-body-item meta-body-info'})
for estreia in html_estreia:
    estreias = estreia.find_all(text = True)
    #print(estreias)
    generos = []
    try:
        generos = estreias[7].replace("\n", "") + ','+ (estreias[7] == None and ('') or estreias[9].replace("\n", ""))
    except IndexError:
        generos = estreias[5]
    estreiasLista.append({'Estreia':estreias[1],\
                            'Genero':generos})
```

Method Join:

```
filmesLista2 = "\n".join("{} , {} , {}".format(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip(filmeLista, diretoresLista, estreiasLista))
print(filmesLista2)
```

entire method output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxed9.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look to this answer, i believe it covers what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: Could you boil this question down to just the three lists you have and the one list you want without all the backstory of how you got the three lists?

Comment: Yes, without the backstory :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try

```py
filmesLista2 = [{**x, **y, **z} for x, y, z in zip(filmeLista, diretoresLista, estreiasLista)]
```

provided that your python version is ≥ 3.5.

See [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona).

The output is as follows:

```
[
{'nome': 'Godzilla vs Kong', 'diretor': 'Adam Wingard', 'Estreia': '29 de abril de 2021', 'Genero': 'Ação,Aventura'},
{'nome': 'Meu Pai', 'diretor': 'Florian Zeller', 'Estreia': '9 de abril de 2021', 'Genero': '/'},
{'nome': 'Velozes & Furiosos 9', 'diretor': 'Justin Lin', 'Estreia': '22 de julho de 2021', 'Genero': 'Ação'},
{'nome': 'Miraculous - Ladybug e Cat Noir', 'diretor': 'Thomas Astruc', 'Estreia': '2021', 'Genero': 'Aventura,Animação'},
{'nome': 'Os Croods 2: Uma Nova Era', 'diretor': 'Will Gluck', 'Estreia': '1 de julho de 2021', 'Genero': 'Aventura,Animação'},
{'nome': 'Pedro Coelho 2: O Fugitivo', 'diretor': 'Emerald Fennell', 'Estreia': 'julho 2021', 'Genero': 'Aventura,Comédia'},
{'nome': 'Bela Vingança', 'diretor': 'Cate Shortland', 'Estreia': '8 de abril de 2021', 'Genero': 'Comédia,Drama'},
{'nome': 'Viúva Negra', 'diretor': 'James Gunn', 'Estreia': '9 de julho de 2021', 'Genero': 'Ação,Aventura'},
{'nome': 'O Esquadrão Suicida', 'diretor': 'Doug Liman', 'Estreia': '5 de agosto de 2021', 'Genero': 'Aventura,Fantasia'},
{'nome': 'Mundo em Caos', 'diretor': 'Felipe Novaes', 'Estreia': '8 de abril de 2021', 'Genero': 'Ação,Ficção Científica'},
{'nome': 'Chorão: Marginal Alado', 'diretor': 'Malcolm D. Lee', 'Estreia': '8 de abril de 2021', 'Genero': '/'},
{'nome': 'Space Jam: Um Novo Legado', 'diretor': 'Simon McQuoid', 'Estreia': '15 de julho de 2021', 'Genero': 'Comédia,Família'},
{'nome': 'Mortal Kombat', 'diretor': 'John Krasinski', 'Estreia': '13 de maio de 2021', 'Genero': 'Ação'},
{'nome': 'Um Lugar Silencioso - Parte II', 'diretor': 'Michael Matthews', 'Estreia': '17 de junho de 2021', 'Genero': 'Fantasia,Terror'}
]
```

Comment: thank you so much! you saved my sleep, now i can go to sleep!